# Pokemon go, only 3 eeveelutions

Tags: pokemon-go

Does anyone know if you can evolve your eevee into more than just a jolteon, flareon, or vaporeon? Ive only seen the three, and im not sure if theyre going to update the game with other eeveelutions or if they already exist and are just extremely rare.

Comment: Pokémon Go only has 151 Pokémon. The 4th Eeveelution is #196. Do you think that's enough information to answer your question?

Comment: I like how easy it is to tell which questions are asked by people who have never known the pain of facing Mewtwo before Dark-types were added, nor the joy or wrecking said Mewtwo with Lv160+ Aerodactyl from the Missingno. glitch... Good times...

Answer (score 4):

The game only has the Kanto Pokedex, which only has Jolteon, Vaporeon and Flareon eeveelutions.

If Niantic adds another region, the eevees should evolve to another eeveelution.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Pokemon Go only includes first generation Pokemon. So no, there are no evolutions for Eevee besides Flareon, Jolteon, and Vaporeon.